# How do I mimic the look&feel of Racket docs when I create my own Scribble documents?

Tags: racket, scribble

I like the look and feel of the [Racket documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/), in terms of style. But when I generate my own [Scribble](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/) documents, the default look is OK, but not quite what I would like in terms of fonts and colors. Where exactly does the styling of the Racket documentation happen?  This would be for the HTML output, not necessarily yet for any TeX/LaTeX I might produce later.  I do see what looks to me like low-level styling info in the documentation for Scribble; maybe I'm not seeing the forest for the trees, or I don't see the special tree with the fruit I need.  If the answer is a pointer to a specific `.scrbl` source file in the Racket repo where this happens, I can probably work out the rest.

Answer (score 3):

For my short term needs, I figured out that if I change

```
#lang scribble/base
```

at the top of my `.scrbl` file to

```
#lang scribble/manual
```

that alone makes my Scribble output look just like Racket documentation.  And that is all I really need for now.  Next I'd love to figure out how I could make my own `scribble/something` that would futher refine the look and feel, or how to tweak fonts and colors.